# Cannot read property of undefined in class

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to javascript so can anyone help me figure out why this code is not working?

I have a class and it calls a cordova barcode scanning function. I've got an example that works, however I want to be able to separate out the function(result) and function(error) and use onSuccess(result) and onFailure(error).

I have no idea why this is happening so if anyone can help that would be great.

EDIT: so ive updated the code based on Stradosphere said however im still getting result is not defined errors.

Full error message:

Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined at barcodeScanner.scanBarcode (barcodeScanner.js:10) at HTMLButtonElement.myFunction (main.js:18)

```
var me = this;
class barcodeScanner {
    constructor() {
        this._barcodeResult = 0;
    }

    scanBarcode() {
        //THIS THROWS result is not defined error 
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(me.onSuccess(result), me.onFailure(error));

        //THIS WORKS
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function (result) {
                me._barcodeResult = result.text;
                alert("Barcode Scanned:" + me._barcodeResult);        
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            }
        );
    }

    onSuccess(result) {
        this._barcodeResult = result.text;
        alert("Barcode Scanned:" + this._barcodeResult);
    }

    onFailure(error) {
        alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: CRice hi i tried implementing the answer in that thread but i didnt seem to work. ive updated the code based on another answer but that still doesnt work. So if you have any ideas whats going wrong i would happy to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner), it appears that `cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan()` expects you to pass a function into it. But you are calling it like this:

```
 cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(me.onSuccess(result), me.onFailure(error));
```

This is passing the *result* of the function `.onSuccess(result)`, but `result` is not defined, so you are getting an error. Additionally, you want `this` to be the class instance, but by defining `me` as `this` outside the class, `me` won't equal the class instance like you want it to. But you don't need it anyway.

Try passing functions in instead:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan((result) => this.onSuccess(result),(error)=> this.onFailure(error))
```

Comment: hi im now getting this error: uncaught TypeError: me.onFailure is not a function

Comment: @Zyie Don't use `me`. Use `this.onFailure ()`.

Comment: Ok that worked. Just one slight change the onFailure takes an error youve given it a result. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a scope issue on your use of this. Try:

```
var me = this; //(put this at class level)
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(me.onSuccess, me.onFailure);
```

Comment: i put the var me = this inside the constructor and i now get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: me is not defined
    at barcodeScanner.scanBarcode (barcodeScanner.js:10)
    at HTMLButtonElement.myFunction (main.js:18)